# Is it possible to see docker swarm internal DNS records?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

Is it possible to see docker swarm internal DNS records at an instant of time ?

I want to see the behaviour in the DNS system when i shutdown one of my nodes which has few services/containers on it .

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out how to do this from within the container?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you could start a container and use `dig` to query the DNS server from the container.

Comment: @dmephin - Yeah i thought about it but for that i have to install dig or change the Dockerfile for any service .  I thought if swarm provides anything to check out the DNS records .